# Excel - how to memorize click-state of a button workbook-wide? (e.g. to show-hide data or join with another button's state)

Tags: excel, vba, buttonclick

*(TLDR: question is until "use-case:")*

I am trying to erase values in an excel column when a button is pressed a second time.

At this stage, I have a button with following code that displays values from another sheet if pressed. The data is just displayed in the current sheet, it will never be more than a number of columns, say max 10, and they will be copied in / removed depending on button state.

(implemented as ActiveX button through developer tools):

```
Private Sub Button_Click()

Worksheets("myworksheet.xlsx").Columns("E").Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Columns("S")

End Sub
```

I would like to store certain values globally for the duration of the session so if another button is pressed, it can get the state of this button too (in order to join data referred to by the two buttons).

What would be the best way to store these values and retrieve them?

PS this is my first foray into Excel vba. Main goal is minimum overhead but still extensible to more logic. So any ugly but quick solution that works up to say 20 params, is also fine with me... "time to market" is critical.

thank you very much for your time and help.

---

*use-case:*

Show all involved tables or objects in a data loading process, from input file to reporting domain - but only show those objects for which the relevant buttons are pressed. E.g. show all target tables in Domain "A", or show all reports using source files in soure feed "X".

button 1 has label "Domain A". If pressed, it will get all Jobs that are listed in the "Domain A" Column in another sheet and display them.

Button 2 has label "CORE Database". If pressed by itself, it will show all values from the "tables" column in the Database Sheet that have value "CORE" in another column.

If both buttons are pressed, I want to display all jobs in Domain A with all tables in "CORE Database" that they have as targets.

Then, if button "CORE Database" is pressed again, ie "toggled off", the display should go back to only showing all Jobs for Domain A.

Now if a third button is pressed, labeled "VIEW Layer", the combination of all views for all jobs in Domain A should show up.

Combining all three buttons should then show the combinaiton of all three.

The logic that is behind this, could be implemented in many was I guess, and I will see how far I get. The starting point is to have a decent location for storing these states, there may be up to 30 buttons if things get really wild.

Each button essentially adds its own column ("Dimension"), and whatever is displayed, will be a cross-section of all of these. So it is important, to know at any time, what buttons are pressed.

Update 2:
some example in data (warning, this goes beyond the original question):
*Jobs* sheet holds jobs and their tables.
*Views* sheet holds views and their source tables.

if only the "Jobs" button is selected, display:
*SOURCE DATA: Jobs, deduplicated*
[image: Jobs]

if only the "View" button is pressed, display all the views in the database, deduplicated.
For example:
[image: Views]

if only the "CORE" button is selected, display all the tables in the core database, for example:
*JOINED DATA: tables, taken from the Jobs sheet and the view sheet, deduplicated* 
(edit: this is inconsistent, as the tables X and Y show up out of nowhere, they could be left out or more jobs showing)
[image: tables]

if the Jobs and Core button is pressed, show (this is directly from the Jobs sheet):
*SOURCE DATA: Jobs and their target tables*
[image: jobs_to_tables]

If the tables and views button is pressed:
(in this example case, View B is not delivered by any job)
*SOURCE DATA: Views and their source tables*
[image: tables_to_views]

(so ViewA uses two tables as source)

if the "Job" and "View" buttons are pressed:
*JOINED DATA: Views and relevant jobs, joined through their matching tables*
[image: jobs_to_views]

and finally if all three buttons are pressed, essentially more columns are shown and more rows are shown, since there is less deduplication:
*JOINED DATA: Views and relevant jobs, joined through their matching tables, showing all*
[image: jobs_views_tables]

(despite the confusing name "B", ViewB is not loaded by jobB. Should have picked different name, in retrospect)

Comment: If you have a lot of data,  probably best to 'store' your temp data on another worksheet (maybe a hidden sheet e.g.) . For your button state, there is no built in way to keep track of how many clicks a button has, but you could write a function to do so, or even just update a global boolean each time it's clicked (i.e. `If myGlobalBool = False Then myGlobalBool = True` - < example for how logic would work)

Comment: wow, thank you for that superfast reply! If you were pressed for time, and expected 15 params max, what would you suggest to use? (ugly = no problem ;))

Comment: Might be best to update you question to be more *specific* about what you are trying to achieve. What kind of data is it? Where is the data on your sheet? Be as descriptive as you can - also add what you have already tried (even if it didn't work)

Comment: ok i will update -but actually you have already helped me in a great way - those seem to be two viable ways forward. I would be happy to accept this as an answer, in case you would give a reply.

Comment: added the use case

Comment: Forget about global booleans, just use toggle buttons. You can insert them from Developer > Insert > ActiveX Controls. 

I'll chuck an answer in with some concepts.

Comment: that actually is what I am using :)

Comment: The key ingredient missing is *where*  and *how* will the data be displayed? On another worksheet? By unhiding already hidden columns? On a userform? From the looks of your question just the first sheet at the moment?

Comment: yes, as per the code fragment, just copy the data into the sheet - and remove it again to build up something else if other buttons are pressed. I need this flexibility because I may be adding different data later, if it gets more stable - and then the unhiding could become messy.

Comment: I've added an answer which will be dynamic to your additions of columns later. You'll just need to change your sheet references and range references to suit your workbook.

Comment: wow... this is really awesome work... THANK You! I will be reading this now, but I am already very thankful for all the energy you put in - it is really helping me out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214050/discussion-between-samuel-everson-and-rusty75).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is based on a new worksheet with 3 activeX toggle buttons (all with default names).

I've first bound a cell to each toggle button - `A1` to `ToggleButton1`, `B1` to `ToggleButton2` and `C1` to `ToggleButton3`. This returns either `TRUE` or `FALSE` to the cell based on the state of the `ToggleButton`.
[ToggleButton control MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/togglebutton-control)

For visuals, here is the source data:
[image: Example source data]

**Note:** As it's not *that* easy to see whcih ones are clicked in at a glance, you can change the back colour of the buttons in the `ToggleButton_Click` event.
Like so:

```
With Sheet1.ToggleButton1
    If .Value = True Then
        .BackColor = &HFF00&
    ElseIf .Value = False Then
        .BackColor = &H8000000F
    End If
End With
End Sub

Private Sub ToggleButton2_Click()
With Sheet1.ToggleButton2
    If .Value = True Then
        .BackColor = &HFF00&
    ElseIf .Value = False Then
        .BackColor = &H8000000F
    End If
End With
End Sub

Private Sub ToggleButton3_Click()
With Sheet1.ToggleButton3
    If .Value = True Then
        .BackColor = &HFF00&
    ElseIf .Value = False Then
        .BackColor = &H8000000F
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

---

I first define the last column dynamically based on the first row of values.
[Info about finding the last row/column](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm)

**Note:** I've included 2 statements for `SourceLastCol` - use one or the other depending on how your sheet is set up - If you leave it as is, it will use the value from the 2nd statement.

Using the last column found, I then loop each cell in the range for row 1 from column A to the last column.

If the value is True it then spits that columns values out into another worksheet (in this case, `Sheet2`) to `TempDestinationRange` using `TempArray`. (See http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx for more info about this method).

It would probably be best to have a `Submit` command button to trigger the sub rather than run it each time a toggle button is clicked (as if you have 30 and someone changes them all that's a lot of redundant worksheet changes).

`Sheet2` output :
[image: Output to sheet2]

```
Sub CheckToggleAndJoinData()

Dim SourceLastCol As Long
Dim SourceLastRow As Long
Dim SourceRange As Range
Dim CellToCheck As Range
Dim TrueRange As Range
Dim DestinationRange As Range
Dim DestinationLastRow As Long
Dim DestinationLastCol As Long
Dim TempArray As Variant

With Sheet1
    SourceLastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "S").End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("S1:S" & SourceLastRow).ClearContents
    SourceLastRow = 0

    SourceLastCol = Sheet1.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'Use this one if there is no data to the right of your source columns.
    SourceLastCol = Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Column 'Use this if there is data to the right of your source columns (note this will not work if there are blank gaps in your source columns)

    Set SourceRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, SourceLastCol))
End With

Dim TrueColumnArray As Variant
Dim ColumnToCheck As Long
Dim ColumnCounter As Long

ColumnCounter = 0
For ColumnToCheck = 1 To SourceLastCol
    With Sheet1
        If .Cells(1, ColumnToCheck).Value = True Then
            ColumnCounter = ColumnCounter + 1
            SourceLastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, ColumnToCheck).End(xlUp).Row
            Set TrueRange = .Range(.Cells(2, ColumnToCheck), .Cells(SourceLastRow, ColumnToCheck))

            DestinationLastCol = Sheet2.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            If ColumnCounter = 1 Then
                Set DestinationRange = Sheet2.Cells(1, DestinationLastCol)
            Else
                 Set DestinationRange = Sheet2.Cells(1, DestinationLastCol + 1)
            End If

            TempArray = TrueRange
            DestinationRange.Resize(UBound(TempArray, 1), 1).Value = TempArray
        End If
    End With
Next ColumnToCheck

End Sub
```

To de-duplicate your data (as mentioned in some comments/edits/chat) you may want to look into using a [Dictionary object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object) as this will store each input value as a Key - ignoring subsequent occurrences of this value.

Comment: wow, thanks for all this work! If I understand correctly, you display all the data from the corresponding "activated" buttons. In my case however, I would like to left join (because starting at the base) based on a shared secondary column. I know, this gets tricky.. A left join B using A."f2" = B."f2" and then display A, B for these values. It needs to be automated, so powerquery is not possible i guess?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with powerquery so I'm not too sure sorry. Edit your question to include some sample inputs and output and I'll edit the answer to take that into account. If not mistaken in my example data you'd want it to show in the first row; `a2, c2` and 2nd row; `a3, c3`?

Comment: basically yes, if "2" is the key column in your case. So I have added more information, with sample data... but as a word of caution,  I have more or less described the full idea, which is beyond the initial question :)  I am hoping to just fix it by creating data columns, dynamically determining the required columns and doing the whole stuff in VBA in a work sheet, then displaying the final columns to the main sheet. Anyway, first some sleep..probably not much more then 6 hours or so, I guess ;)

Comment: thanks again Samuel! There is a lot of useful information in there - which certainly helped me to go into the right direction. Arrays is a great idea, since it allows me to do some comparison logic as well.

Comment: thanks for the links, I have bookmarked the page :)

Answer (score 0):

*-edit: I wrote this BEFORE Samuel's answer, so that is obviously making this irrelevant :)*
for now I will just go with following solution, it works for me, beauty is not so important right now

-update: I am now going with global variables, of course my programmermind tells me this is risky and dangerous, but I just need results for now, and they are booleans for states, only. Any suggestions are still very welcome.
Here is some code that I have now:

```
Public CORE_Pressed As Boolean

Sub clearCol(colLabel As String)
  Columns(colLabel).ClearFormats
  Columns(colLabel).ClearComments
  Columns(colLabel).ClearHyperlinks
  Columns(colLabel).Clear
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  SLJM_Pressed = False

End Sub      

Private Sub CORE_Button_Click()
CORE_Pressed = Not CORE_Pressed
If CORE_Pressed = True Then
  Worksheets("CORE.xlsx").Columns("E").Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Columns("S")
Else
  clearCol ("S")
End If

End Sub
```

I will probably move the button handling into a central function, but this is just to show the current approach.

Also many thanks for the comments posted by Samuel Everson, they gave a very interesting alternative for when things need to be more "professional". global variables are ugly I know.